# Formula for searching a range and returning column headers

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, flatten

I've been working on, or at least trying to develop, a formula that goes through an array of cells, finds the max value and returns a cell that has the month that max value was found in.

[Link to Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YHU_24_F40bGQ9C-5dfRhWuqZ2s6GOB-sEkLiakNQJY/edit?usp=sharing)

The array I'm trying to search through is B14:M21. Once the max value is found in a column, I'd like to return a value from B13:M13. This return value (the month column where the value was found) is going to be displayed in cell H4.

This same concept would also need to be applied to finding the year the max value is found, just in terms of rows instead of columns. I've tried doing `hlookup`, `vlookup`, `query`, `index/match`, etc. and none of it has worked for this application.

Comment: Your goal is not clear to me. Are you planning to manually type the values into I4 and I5 and then only want the month and year returned in H4 and H5, respectively? Or are you wanting the formulas to find and return both the month/year and the values? (I don't understand why you would manually enter values in I4 and I5 if they are obtainable from the data set via formula). And though you didn't ask this, are the values in N14:N22 being manually entered somehow? (If so, again, my question would be "Why?" when formulas can easily handle that.)

Comment: @ErikTyler Those values are obtained by formula. I just simplified the original sheet to make it a bit easier to go through. H4 and H5 are obtained via a max formula, the range B14:M21 is calculated through a series of other sheets respectively named by year. The only data that's entered manually is each days sales on the respective tab. Link to original sheet here > 

[Sales](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DbN5pTFPSUYTYi_RcoaTtGDTZhsX2Bn89SkREFY3e0U/edit#gid=1585276011)

Comment: Ah, all right. Looks like Player0 has you covered then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=FLATTEN(SPLIT(INDEX(SORT(SPLIT(
 FLATTEN(B13:M13&"♦"&A14:A21&"♠"&B14:M21), "♠"), 2, 0), 1, 1), "♦"))
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like that works!! Is there any way to do that with the year as well? I'm trying to understand how this formula works.

Comment: @Richard see the yellow cells: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bRlSeIFE-9-0DrfQxR5wDNGN7oTa3hOtDVXkyATA7YA/edit#gid=0

Comment: @Richard or blue cells if you want it combined

Comment: Ah I see how this works now! Thank you!